# How can I implement user role permissions using node js, express and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have currently started learning node js. I want to implement user authentication and authorization using nodejs, express and mongodb. When the user hit the /admin route, it must redirect user to admin. And there will be login menu where normal user can login. As for exapmle spatie laravel package https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use external libraries like http://www.passportjs.org/

This library offers you different methods to authenticate your users, take a look at different strategies on its search bar.

You can find a lot of articles and working examples related to Mongo Passport and Express authentication.

Comment: Something like => https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619

Comment: Thanks Jac. Can you suggest me something for multiple roles and permissions something like ACL.

Comment: If you are doing it as exercise you can look at examples like this one => https://gist.github.com/danwit/e0a7c5ad57c9ce5659d2